# JAVA - Android error: The application has stopped unexpectedly please try again

Tags: android, android-emulator, meta-tags

I made an app which is just working fine. But when i click on "cancel" or "ok" button, instead of linking me to result.java, the simulator give me "The application has stopped unexpectedly please try again" Here's the code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName; 
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.CursorJoiner.Result;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class lib_main extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void onAddClick (View botton){

        AutoCompleteTextView title = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.Title);
        AutoCompleteTextView author = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.Author); 
        AutoCompleteTextView isbn = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.ISBN);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this,Result.class);

        intent.putExtra("Title", title.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("Author", author.getText().toString()); 
        intent.putExtra("ISBN", isbn.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onCancelClick(View botton){

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this,Result.class));

        intent.putExtra("Cancel","Cancel");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

this is result.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Result extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);

        TextView resultText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultText);

        Bundle bundle =getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle.getString("Cancel")!= null)
        {
           resultText.setText("operation cancel");
        }
        else
        {  
           String book =bundle.getString ("Title");
           String title =bundle.getString ("Author");
           String isbn =bundle.getString ("ISBN");
           resultText.setText(getString (R.string.resultOk)+""+book+""+ title+""+isbn);

        }
    }
}
```

the error log write "No command output when running:'am start-n com.Library.doc/com.Library.doc.lib_main-a android.intent.action.MAIN-c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' in device emulator-5554"

Comment: Please try to format your code into a form that can be read with decency. Did you search stackoverflow?:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515257/no-command-output-when-running-am-start-n