# No command output when running: 'am start -n

Tags: android, android-emulator

Has anyone ever seen this error while trying to run an android application in the emulator?

No command output when running: 'am start -n

If so how were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out my problem.. FYI - I uninstall jdk + jre and reinstalled... fixed the issue....

It looks like on a windows pc you have to use the 32 bit version of the JDK with the android sdk.. weird.

-Mike

Answer (score 0):

I am working with the linux version and i have the same issue. The only way i found is to run twice the application from eclipse !

Best regards
.P