# No command output when running: 'am start -n Error

Tags: android

When I run my application in eclipse and click on a button to start a new Activity my application force closes and I get this error:

```
null
Error
Sat Apr 23 19:53:21 CDT 2011
No command output when running: 'am start -n com.example.lostalarmclock/com.example.lostalarmclock.LostAlarmClock -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' on device emulator-5554

com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:408)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:276)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.ActivityLaunchAction.doLaunchAction(ActivityLaunchAction.java:74)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.launchApp(AndroidLaunchController.java:1146)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.clientChanged(AndroidLaunchController.java:1489)
at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.clientChanged(AndroidDebugBridge.java:868)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.update(Device.java:398)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.update(Client.java:835)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleAppName.handleAPNM(HandleAppName.java:90)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleAppName.handleChunk(HandleAppName.java:64)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.callHandler(MonitorThread.java:414)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:322)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: was the emulator started before or does it started when you run the project? Have you tried to search on stackoverlow? Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515257/no-command-output-when-running-am-start-n

Comment: The emulator starts when I run the project and I did check out the other page but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 14):

This error killed my many hours... Finally below steps helped.. Let me share so that some one can benefited...

In eclipse Increase the ADB connection timeout by following below steps

**Window -->  Preferences**

Select **Andriod -> DDMS** from left panel

Increase value of "**ADB connection time out (ms)**"

Comment: May help, but it's not the cause.

Comment: I got the same error while i used HttpPost and Http Client i increased the ADB connection to 8000 finally it worked thank you @Fahad

Answer (score 2):

i had same problem then i notice on the website to access the eclipse ini file which is notepad file and change the settings from

```
-Xms40m 
-Xmx256m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Recommended settings for Android development:

```
-Xms128m 
-Xmx512m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my project used other projects SDKs, like Facebook and Aviary. All I had to do was cleaning Facebook-SDK and Aviary-SDK projects that were imported in my workspace!

If anybody else is having this problem, try just cleaning the projects that are used in your project.

Comment: Did you mean "Build & Clean" ? Or deleting of old files ? or what exactly ? Be specific.

Comment: @SashaZd I'm really sorry, it's my first time posting here. Yes, i meant "Build & Clean", like going to Project -> Clean with "Build Automatically" checked.