# No command output when running: 'am start -n com.examples.androidproject1/com.examples.androidproject1.MainActivity

Tags: android, eclipse

Am doing project on Android, when I update some code and try to run that Android Project, that **Android Project wont run on emulator**. In **Error Log** it displaying this error

`No command output when running: 'am start -n com.examples.androidproject1/ com.examples.androidproject1.MainActivity  -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' on device emulator-5554.`

But my code don't have any errors. When I try to run 3rd or 4th time then only this project run on emulator. Till two to three times it displaying same error on **Error Log.** Whats wrong on my **Eclipse** ? or what was my mistake ?

Comment: Maybe this will help.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16153608/1900511